# multiple install options in installshield

Tags: windows, windows-installer, installshield

Im new to using installshield, currently im using installsheild 10.

i am trying to create a install file where the they can choose the install

for example

() install package A
() install package B

Depending on there answer depends on what files are installed.

like i said i have been looking everywhere for a sample file to download soi would be able to teach myself but i have gave up as its been ongoing for 2 days.

I have tried many things like the options "complete or custom"

thank you in advance but please keep it simple for me to follow :)

Or is there any easy software that can cater for this?

Comment: or do you know any easy that can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you to read about ["Features"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) first, and understand how MSI works. There is answer on your question regarding the separate packages. But if you have already 2 MSI and want to create installer which will install first, second or both - read information about "Chained MSI".

Answer (score 1):

Please try with Feature condition mean make a single MSI with 2 Features and set Two Public Properties for those Like FEATURE1,FEATURE2.set condndition to feature in navigation tree . once you create these add the files to two features seperately.when end user tryes to install let them install through cmd or batch file or vbs to enter parameters like

```
Msiexec/i"app.msi" FEATURE1=condition name
```

hope this will work